# Using grunt-critical with local URL as source

Tags: php, gruntjs

I installed [grunt-critical](https://github.com/bezoerb/grunt-critical) into a PHP project and would like to generate CSS from a dynamically rendered page. I guess the simplest method is use localhost as the HTML source.

So I used the [official example](https://github.com/bezoerb/grunt-critical#usage) grunt task and tweaked it:

```
critical: {
  test: {
    options: {
      base: './',
      css: [
        'web/css/style.min.css'
      ],
      width: 320,
      height: 70
    },
    src: 'http://localhost:9000/',
    dest: 'web/css/critical.css'
  }
},
```

Executing `grunt critical` throws an error:

```
Running "critical:test" (critical) task
Unhandled rejection Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:203:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:288:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:893:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)
```

No request is reaching the web server though. Am I missing a dependency or is this not the right way to go?

(Edit) Previously I thought PHP server was returning an error, but it was unrelated! There is no request log on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Remote URL fetching worked great using the [grunt-criticalcss](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunt-criticalcss) NPM module instead, tweaking the official example as follows:

```
criticalcss: {
    custom: {
        options: {
            url: "http://localhost:9000",
            width: 1200,
            height: 900,
            outputfile: "web/css/critical.css",
            filename: "web/css/style.css",
            buffer: 800*1024,
            ignoreConsole: false
        }
    }
},
```